# SAAJ request xml , envelope prefix changes itself

Tags: java, web-services, soap, saaj

I am facing a problem, where my request xml , which I build using SAAJ has a Envelope prefix as SOAP-ENV:Envelope when I run it in eclipse main method. Whereas when I put the code in the Weblogic 11g I checked the prefix has become env:Envelope. The Envelope xml I was using is "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/".

I will be glad if anyone tell me what is happening, and what the effect is if I send the request with either of the prefix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The prefix should not matter, as long as it references the right uri in the namespace declaration. However... There are nitwits, no-nos, or whatever you like to call them, that implement things in a wrong way (manually parse the xml) and expect a specific prefix.